# Passport js is returning "Missing Credentials" error for Login

Tags: api, express, jwt, sequelize.js, passport.js

I am creating api end points using express js. I have used `passport js` and `jwt` for user authentication. Using Sequelize to interact with database.

In Controller I am getting `{message: 'Missing Credentials'}` error.

passport.js file:

```
passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password', session: false }, 
async (email, password, done) => {
          try {
            const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: email }});
              if (user === null) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'bad username' });
              } else {
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(response => {
                  if (response !== true) {
                    console.log('passwords do not match');
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'passwords do not match' });
                  }
                  console.log('user found & authenticated');
                  // note the return needed with passport local - remove this return for passport JWT
                  return done(null, user);
                });
              }
          } catch (err) {
            return done(err);
          }
        })
    );
```

LoginController.js

```
const loginUser = async (req, res, next) => {

    passport.authenticate('login', (err, user, info) => {
        console.log(err); // null
        console.log(user); //false
        console.log(info); // { message: 'Missing Credentials' }
        if (err || (!user)) {
            res.status(419).json({
                message: "Incorrect Username or Password",
                isSuccess: false
            });
        } else {

            try {

                req.login(user, { session: false }, async (error) => {
                    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.email }, jwt_secret);
                    res.status(200).json({
                        message: "Login Successfull",
                        isSuccess: true,
                        token
                    });
                });

            } catch (error) {
                res.status(419).json({
                    message: "Incorrect Username or Password",
                    isSuccess: false
                });
            }
        }
    })(req, res, next);
};
```

Please help me to find the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try something like this and remove the **where**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(email, done) {
    User.findOne({ email: email}, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

[passportjs .findOne()](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/username-password/)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvinience. I have edited the code and I think 'LocalStrategy' is not getting called.

Comment: I tried that, but the same result. I am trying to log email to console. Its not happening. So, I am guessing LocalStrategy is not getting called.